# Slightly complex regex for username

Tags: regex

I need help to build a regex for a username.

There are three sections to the username. First character, middle group, last character.

Here are the rules I have to follow:

- The first character must be a lower case letter, e.g. `(a-z)`
- The middle group of characters must be 4 or more characters letters and numbers only, e.g. `(a-zA-Z0-9)`
- The middle group must contain at least one letter AND one number
- The last character must be a number `(0-9)`

Some examples:

```
hTes38      (i.e. h Tes3 8)
j347k6      (i.e. j 347k 6)
atksde21D2  (i.e. a tksde21D 2)
```

Here is what I have so far, which is almost there:

```
^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]\w{1,}[0-9]$
```

But the middle group is not correct, I don't know how to enforce the 'has to include one letter and one number' rule.

Comment: Why does your attempt have a `\w` in it? And why do you have `{1,}` when it's supposed to be 4 or more?

Comment: @ooga At one stage I was using a 4, and then trying to get it working with words at one stage, hence the (\w) and {1, }, and trying many other variations. Hence the inaccurate regex I had posted. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a two look aheads (one for a letter and one for a digit) to assert that the middle section has at least one letter and one digit:

```
^[a-z](?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d.*.$)[a-zA-Z\d]{4,}\d$
```

Note that the look ahead for a digit `(?=.*\d.*.$)` ends in `.*.$`, which makes sure the final digit of the whole input does not get counted as a digit in the middle section (the last dot consumes the last digit so it's not available for `\d` to match).

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/9nEBG8KPoP) with your samples and some edge cases.

See [this external article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for a good description of look arounds.

Comment: There is a small mistake: the first char should be (a-z).

Comment: Trying to get my head around 'look aheads', many thanks!!! Reading up on this to understand it fully.

Answer (score 1):

Bohemian has the right answer if you need to do this in a single regex.  However, depending on which language/platform you are using, it may be cleaner and faster to run multiple regexes connected by `if` statements.

```
if input.matches('^([a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,})([0-9])$'))
  if (matches[1].matches('\d') && matches[1].matches('[a-zA-Z]')
    return $true

return $false
```

Also works if you can't use a lookahead.

Comment: Using this in ASP.NET MVC (C#) in data annotations, and AFAIK has to be in a single statement. But thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more direct and primitive, you could always try

```
\d[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]|\d[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]|
\d[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]|
[a-zA-Z0-9]\d[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]\d[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z]|
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]\d[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z0-9]|
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\d[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\d|
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]\d|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z]\d
```

for the middle part. This seemed to work just fine but I didn't test it with every possible combination.

The general logic behind this is to alternate the position of the digit (from position 0 to 1 to 2 to 3), then alternate the position of the character among the remaining positions (e.g. if the digit is in position 1, the character alternates from 0 to 2 to 3), and finally fill the remaining two positions with either digits or characters.

Note: I'm definitely not claiming this to be the best solution, but it's a solution nevertheless.

Comment: Good to know, will make a note of this approach, thanks. Always good to have another approach.

Comment: Don't use `\w` for this problem, as it matches `_`

Comment: Whoops, I thought I managed to avoid that trap but I guess not. It also matched digits, which wasn't what I intended. Anyway, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for clarity/simplicity, and are not restricted to a single regex:

```
import re
s = "hTes38"
first, middle, last = s[0], s[1:-1], s[-1]
answer = bool(first.isalpha() and           # The first character must be a lower case letter
         last.isdigit() and                 # The last character must be a number
         len(middle) >= 4 and               # The middle group of characters must be 4 or more characters
         re.search("[a-zA-Z]", middle) and  # The middle group must contain at least one letter
         re.search(r"\d", middle) and       # AND one number
         re.match(r"[a-zA-Z\d]+$", middle)) # The middle group of characters must be letters and numbers only
```